# Laravel -How to store image file provided by user

Tags: php, html, laravel

so I have a simple HTML file insert box,

```
<input id="image" type="file" name="image" value="{{ old('image') }}" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" class="black-font">
```

but after inserting the image and going to a different page, the website doesn't save the image, which means I cannot use it later. I've looked around for some ways to get around this but I couldn't find anything that worked. is there any way I can store the file? Or another alternative that makes me be able to use them in another page of the website?

If it helps, I have a SQL table called "event" with an attribute `image` where I'd like to store the link/path to the image provided.

Answer (score 5):

By default, public disks use local drivers and store these files under `storage/app/public`. To access them via the web, you need to create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`.
Go into the `.env` file, create a variable called `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER`, and set it to the public, as shown below:

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
```

Next, use the command below in order to create the symbolic link.

```
php artisan storage:link
```